# is this a candidate for a sql groupby query?

Tags: sql

I have two tables: **TableA** (`ID [int, pk], Name [string])` and **TableB** `(ID [int, pk], TableA_ID [int, fk], Name [string], DateStamp [datetime (dd/mm/yyyy hh:MM:ss)])`. There is a one-to-many relationship between TableA and TableB.

An inner join on the two tables will give me the following results:

```
TableA.ID, TableA.Name, TableB.Name, TableB.DateStamp
        1,    'File A', 'Version 1', 01/01/2009 15:00:00
        1,    'File A', 'Version 2', 05/01/2009 08:15:00
        1,    'File A', 'Version 3', 06/01/2009 19:33:00
        2,    'File B', 'Version 1', 03/01/2009 09:10:00
        2,    'File B', 'Version 2', 20/01/2009 20:00:00
        3,    'File C', 'Version 1', 01/01/2009 17:00:00
```

What I actually want is the following (each row from TableA and the last matching row from TableB):

```
TableA.ID, TableA.Name, TableB.Name, TableB.DateStamp
        1,    'File A', 'Version 3', 06/01/2009 19:33:00
        2,    'File B', 'Version 2', 20/01/2009 20:00:00
        3,    'File C', 'Version 1', 01/01/2009 17:00:00
```

This is the query that I'm using to achieve this:

```
SELECT ta.ID, ta.Name, tb.Name, tb.DateStamp
FROM TableA ta INNER JOIN TableB tb ON ta.ID = tb.TableA_ID
WHERE tb.ID IN (
 SELECT TOP 1 tb2.ID 
 FROM TableB tb2 
 WHERE tb2.TableA_ID = ta.ID 
 ORDER BY tb2.DateStamp DESC)
```

That works but my gut feeling is that I'm not doing this in the "best way". It looks like it is a candidate for an aggregation query (i.e. groupby) but I didn't have any luck with that. In the end I always had to use a subquery to get the row I'm after in TableB.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no requirement to do GROUP BY here, this should be solved through a correlated sub-query:

```
SELECT
  TableA.ID, 
  TableA.Name, 
  TableB.Name, 
  TableB.DateStamp
FROM
  TableA
  INNER JOIN TableB ON 
    TableA.ID = TableB.TableA_ID
    AND TableB.DateStamp = (
      SELECT MAX(DateStamp) 
      FROM TableB
      WHERE TableA_ID = TableA.ID
    )
```

An additional GROUP BY is only necessary if you have more than one record in `TableB` with equal `TableA_ID` *and* equal `DateStamp`.

---

For the specific example you've shown, a GROUP BY query *happens to produce* the correct result. It's still wrong, because the correct result is more a side-effect in this situation.

```
SELECT
  TableA.ID, 
  TableA.Name, 
  MAX(TableB.Name) Max_TableBName, 
  MAX(TableB.DateStamp) Max_TableBDateStamp
FROM
  TableA
  INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.ID = TableB.TableA_ID
GROUP BY
  TableA.ID, 
  TableA.Name
```

This relies on the coincidence that `MAX(TableB.Name)` is in fact the value you want to get out, and it is aligned with `MAX(TableB.DateStamp)`. But since this correlation is a mere accident, the GROUP BY query is wrong.

Comment: I was looking at the top level group by use in this situation, and came to similar conclusions as yours.

Comment: I'd suggest using TableB.TableB_ID in the first query if possible (i.e. if it has the same ordering as DateStamp), as integer comparison is always faster than date comparison.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot silently imply a TableB.TableB_ID that is strictly monotonic increasing.

Comment: Yes @Tomalak, certainly. I was actually talking to the OP.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try RANK() OVER function:

```
-- Test data
DECLARE @TableA TABLE (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @TableA
SELECT 1, 'File A' UNION
SELECT 2, 'File B' UNION
SELECT 3, 'File C'

DECLARE @TableB TABLE (ID INT, TableAID INT, Name VARCHAR(20), 
  DateStamp DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @TableB
SELECT 1, 1, 'Version 1', '01/01/2009 15:00:00' UNION
SELECT 2, 1, 'Version 2', '01/05/2009 08:15:00' UNION
SELECT 3, 1, 'Version 3', '01/06/2009 19:33:00' UNION
SELECT 4, 2, 'Version 1', '01/03/2009 09:10:00' UNION
SELECT 5, 2, 'Version 2', '01/20/2009 20:00:00' UNION
SELECT 6, 3, 'Version 1', '01/01/2009 17:00:00'

-- Actually answer
SELECT M.ID, M.AName, M.BName, M.DateStamp FROM
(   SELECT RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY A.ID ORDER BY B.DateStamp DESC) AS N, 
    A.ID, A.Name AS AName, B.Name AS BName, B.DateStamp
    FROM @TableA A INNER JOIN @TableB B ON A.ID = B.TableAID
) M WHERE M.N = 1
```

See [2. Last Date selection with grouping - using RANK() OVER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488020/what-is-your-most-useful-sql-trick-to-avoid-writing-more-code/557238#557238)

Comment: Your answer would be *much* clearer if you differentiate between the data insertions and the actual select statement. I would actually remove the inserts if I were you, because they are not actually part of the answer.

Comment: I thought it's easear to copy whole answer with test data at once... but I'm steppin' towards my customers :) and volia - comments show you the way.

Comment: Thanks. It's much clearer this way. I would suggest that you move the actual answer to the top, because most people will be interested in it, rather than in test data.

Comment: Hosam, if I do this, there will be no point in test data at all. What I'm trying to achive putting test data and using it in answer - is an easy, friendly copy&run format. Everyone can copy this query and test it immediately. And even use my test data for own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make a query using analytical functions. In Oracle you can do:

```
select distinct
       A.Id
,      A.Name
,      first_value(B.Name)      over (partition by B.id
                                      order     by B.DateStamp desc)   BName
,      first_value(B.DateStamp) over (partition by B.id
                                      order     by B.DateStamp desc)   DateStamp
from   TableA A inner join TableB B  on A.id = B.id
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use group by you can use:

```
select 
    ta.id, ta.name, tb.name, tb.dateStamp
from 
    tableA ta 
    inner join tableB tb on ta.id = tb.tablea_id
    inner join (
        select tablea_id, max(DateStamp) as maxDateStamp from tableB
        group by tablea_id
    ) latestB 
        on tb.tablea_id = latestB.tablea_id
        and tb.DateStamp = latestB.maxDateStamp
```

But i will return multiple records if you have multiple entries in tableB with the same value of DateStamp  referencing  same row in tableA

Answer (score 0):

You can't reliably get more than one field from the B table in a grouping, but you can join the B table against the result to get the other fields:

```
select x.ID, x.Name, b.Name, b.DateStamp
from (
  select a.ID, a.Name, max(b.DateStamp) as DateStamp
  from TableA a
  inner join TableB b on b.TableA_ID = a.ID
  group by a.ID, a.Name
) x
inner join TableB b on b.TableA_ID = x.ID and b.DateStamp = x.DateStamp
```